# Attribute not defined error, even though it is defined on a global scope

Tags: python

I'm a newbie to python so please bear with me. I was making a class that contains the make, model, and fuel of a car and was experimenting with the set and get methods to try and learn their use. The issue I'm running into is when I try to update my `tank` attribute by running my `setFuel` method and print out the updated fuel integer I get the error `tank is not defined` even though I defined it all the way above. Why is this occurring and how can I fix it?

I added comments all over my code to explain what I tried to do to help you understand my code. Any help is appreciated thanks in advance.

```
class Car:
    tank = 0 #to keep track of fuel
    make = ""
    model = "" #to keep track of model
    
    def __init__(self, make, model, fuel):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.fuel = fuel
        

    #returns the amout of fuel currently in the tank(as an integer)   
    def getFuel(self):
        return int(self.fuel)

    #sets the amounts of fuel currently in the tank(as an integer)
    def setFuel(self, tank):
        self.tank = int(tank)

    #returns the make and model of the car as a string
    def getType(self):
        return str(self.make),(self.model)

    def printFuel(self):
        print(self.fuel)

#Instantiate a new Car in a variable
myCar = Car("Ford", "Escort", 10)
yourCar = Car("Ford", "Escape", 14)

#print statement that prints the result of the "getFuel"
#method of the "myCar" object
myCar.printFuel()
yourCar.printFuel()

#Change the "tank" attribute to modify the fuel in the tank using
#setFuel method of the "myCar" and "yourCar" object
#subtract 7 from from the tank
myCar.setFuel(tank-7)
#subtract 5 from the tank 
yourCar.setFuel(tank-5)

#print statement that prints the result of the "getFuel"
#method of the "myCar" and "yourCar" object
print(myCar.getFuel())
print(yourCar.getFuel())
print(myCar.getType())
print(yourCar.getType())
```

Comment: And just for your edification, that's not "global scope".  `tank` is a class member variable, just like `make` and `model`.  If always needs to be qualified with an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this:

```
class Car:
    tank = 0 
    make = ""
    model = ""
```

`tank`, `make`, and `model` are class variables shared by all instances, so `myCar` and `yourCar` will share the same `tank`. Read the Python doc for more details about [Class and Instance Variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables).

Because the tank of a car is part of every car (every instance) is better to use instance variables. So is better to write these vars inside `__init__`:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, make, model, fuel):
        self.tank = 0 
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.fuel = fuel
```

Now, `tank` is an instance variable. To access it, use `myCar.tank` (here `myCar` is an instance of the object `Car`). So, to subtract fuel from the tank do:

```
myCar.setFuel(myCar.tank - 7)
```

EDIT: Your code is not reducing the fuel when you print it because you have another problem with your code. Look at your `setFuel` function, it is setting the `tank` and not the `fuel`. Change to:

```
def setFuel(self, fuel):
    self.fuel = int(fuel)
```

Also when you set the fuel in `myCar`, you are using `myCar.tank - 7` where `tank` is equal to `0`. So what you need is to do is:

```
myCar.setFuel(myCar.fuel - 7)
```

I think a better idea will be to make a function inside the `Car` object to reduce the fuel, and in this function check if the Car has enough fuel (because you cant'n have `-x` fuel, right?), like this:

```
def reduceFuel(self, fuel_used):
    if self.fuel - fuel_used < 0:
        raise ValueError("Not enough fuel")
    else:
        self.fuel -= fuel_used
```

and to use:

```
myCar.reduceFuel(7)
```

Comment: This is not working when I print the getFuel() method afterward I am getting the same amount of fuel without the subtraction of 7 and 5 from the set method. @franco Morero

Comment: @anon20010813 read my new edit, hope it help you

Answer (score 1):

You need `myCar.setFuel(myCar.tank-7)` and `yourCar.setFuel(yourCar.tank-5)`.  You might consider adding a `useFuel` method to make that easier.

Comment: This is not working. When I print it I get the same number of fuel without the substruction. and when I global tank and try to print it again I get 'Car" object has no attribute 'tank'. @Tim Roberts

Comment: Of course you do, because `setFuel` is setting the `tank` value, and `printFuel` is printing the `fuel` value.  You need to straighten out your naming.